# Rider C# - Disable "Thread" on the side of the current debug line

Tags: rider

I am debugging an application and I want to disable the string with @ circled in red in the following image:

[image: Capture]

Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to disable the inline view of values, you can do that by going to `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Data Views` and disabling the **`Show values inline`** option.

If, however, you want to just remove that value in specific, I don't believe there is a way to do that currently.

Instead, you can use the `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute to specify how you want a class of field to be displayed: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute), or use `DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)` to have it not be displayed at all. Note that these attributes affect the variables pane as well, not just the inline view.

Comment: Thanks, I want to keep the inline variable values so I will just suffer with that value in there as well